# VSTS Release Failing due to file in use on remote server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, azure-pipelines

Before I state the question I am aware this may be more of a server administration question however I am seeking an answer that involves fixing / modifying the VSTS release process instead of dealing with server permissions (I don't believe this is a server issue).

I have a VSTS Build definition and Release definition.
The release definition copies the files from the build to a remote server (an IIS site).

My problem is that this process fails roughly 60% of the time.

Log files showing failure error:

```
2017-04-06T17:06:07.3886551Z Executing the powershell script: D:\BuildAgent\agent\tasks\IISWebAppDeploy\1.4.3\Main.ps1
2017-04-06T17:06:07.5605268Z Starting deployment of IIS Web Deploy Package : \\server01\Deploy\patrol\dev\rest_service\822\822.zip
2017-04-06T17:06:07.6542742Z Performing deployment in parallel on all the machines.
2017-04-06T17:06:07.6542742Z Deployment started for machine: SERVER01 with port 5985.
2017-04-06T17:06:27.9820654Z Deployment status for machine SERVER01 : Failed
2017-04-06T17:06:28.0133029Z Deployment failed on machine SERVER01 with following message : System.Exception: Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
2017-04-06T17:06:28.0445759Z ##[error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one or more machines failed.
2017-04-06T17:06:28.0445759Z ##[error]For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/iisextnreadme
```

I circumvate the problem by manually remoting into the server and deleting the contents of the target directory manually. I've discovered that each time the release is failing, my manual delete causes a warning to popup that an .exe file is being used by another process. My suspicion is that this is the reason the release is failing.

Is there some extra step that can be added to a release to force delete / clear the target directory?

Comment: You should probably instead identify *what process* is using the file. And then make arrangements to stop that process as part of your release and then restart it. Or eliminate that process. See [How do you find what process is holding a file open in Windows?](http://serverfault.com/questions/1966)

Comment: Can you share which file is being used and which process is using it just as mason mentioned?

Comment: There is Take App Offline option of IIS Web Deployment step/task, try to check this option. On the other hand, try to stop the corresponding website before deploy. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lemoinek.IISutilities）

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows Machine File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task to copy files from build to a remote server. And select **Clean Target** so that before copy files to remote server, it will clean the target destination folder firstly.

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the process I follow. I have that step in my Release. I believe the problem is that the Clean fails, due to a file being locked. I don't get why it only fails some of the time though....The files being copied is a .net core mvc app, and the server uses IIS 7.

Comment: But the power shell script for windows machine files copy should call as `\path\to\agent/\_work\_tasks\WindowsMachineFileCopy_731004d4-1d66-4f70-8c05-638018b22210\1.0.40\WindowsMachineFileCopy.ps1`.